# Is there any way to reduce AngularJS bundle size (with Webpack)

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I am trying to build an AngularJS app (v1.7.x) and the production file size is really huge.

The original dependency in node_module is **1.30 MB** and **170 kB** (min). I imported and tried a basic `console.log`. But the build file is **3.40 MB**

So, Is there any dependencies which I should use OR from your recommend. I am building a basic weather application. (using fetch and ng-repeat)

Currently, I have only these.

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.7.9"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "json-server": "^0.15.1",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
}
```

P.S. I try import **angular.min.js** from node_module but I think it is not a proper way to use `require()` with an absolute path.

Comment: It is probably not angularJS that bloats your bundle, use webpack-analyzer to check what is going on inside your bundle

Comment: The script bundle size around 3MB suggests webpack hasn't performed tree shaking (which it does in production builds).

Answer (score 1):

I found my problems.

My scripts in **package.json** is

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config ./webpack.config.js --mode production"
}
```

But in my **webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development'
}
```

The script is not override the config file even it flagged as production. Now I removed and tried again. My bundle's size was reduced to **3.19 kB**.